# How do you route return packets through same gateway doing the port forwarding?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, routes, ip

**DESCRIPTION**
I have HTTP and SMTP Linux servers and two Linux routers I created using firewalld on the same LAN.  Both routers act great as Internet gateways.  One works great to handle port forwarding of public incoming to the servers in the LAN.  I use a mobile device not on wifi, but cell only, to test outside traffic, loading a page.

However, I'm trying to get the second router to be a redundant backup and point to the same servers using different public IPs.  The problem is each server only works with the port forwarding coming from its default gateway IP.  If I switch the HTTP servers gateway IP to the other router, it then only works with the other router's port forwarding, but never both at the same time, despite adding both gateways to the HTTP server's routing table with different metrics.

To be clear, it always receives the packets from both routers, and it attempts to return packets to the public client IP (mobile IP when testing).

I can see from TCPDUMP that it returns packets to the public IP that initiated it.  But, the clients, be it web browsers or SMTP clients, can never complete the session, such as loading the page.  I suspect it sees the packets coming from a different server with a different public IP, and does not associate them with the session, dropping them. I have to use mobile to test outside, so cannot TCPDUMP that.  But, the behavior when I switch the gateways is pretty strong evidence that's what happening.

**QUESTION**: How can I get it to return the packets out of the gateway where it received the port forwarding from instead of using its default gateway, or otherwise resolve this?

*NOTE*: If I allow masquerade on the internal zone of a router for all sources, the client loads the page without a problem.  But, THIS IS NOT AN OPTION as it is a huge security problem as the servers only see the IP of the routers, not the client public IPs, turning an SMTP server into an open relay and having no way to secure by IP.  This helps confirm the routing dilemma.  It understandably resolves it as it will always route back to the router that did the port forwarding since that becomes the destination IP regardless of which gateway it uses.

This also works just fine internally via all public IPs, probably because I allow masquerading on the internal zones when the source is internal.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about Linux or network configuration. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: There is no fix. You have two conflicting requirements. You want to hide the source IP address of the machines (that's why you need NAT) but you don't want to hide the source IP address of the machines (because you think that's a security problem). Either they use their real IP address (which the other machine can't reach through the gateway) or they don't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz restating the challenge doesn't mean there is no fix. One thing I'm looking into is using virtual interfaces with each virtual device having a different gw on a different subnet.  Throwing out security is not an option.  I accidentally made that mistake once, only to discover Russian bots were going nuts open relaying on my SMTP server for a week, and that the IP got put on a lot of blacklists, with it being nearly impossible to get Google (and thus all GMail recipients) to retest and forgive.